# Reliably tracking time from the server

Tags: javascript, php, time

I have HTML like this:

```
<span id="servertime" data-timestamp="<?=round(microtime(true)*1000)?>">
    <?=date("d/M/Y H:i:s")?>
</span>
```

JavaScript then runs like so:

```
(function() {
    var clock = $("#servertime"),
        local = Date.now(),
        offset = local - clock.data("timestamp"),
        s = window.serverTime = new Date();
    s.setTime(clock.data("timestamp"));

    function pad(n) {return n<10?"0"+n:n;}
    var mon = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";

    setInterval(function() {
        var now = Date.now();
        s.setTime(now - offset);
        clock.text(
            pad(s.getUTCDate())
            +"/"+mon.substr(s.getUTCMonth()*3,3)
            +"/"+s.getUTCFullYear()
            +" "+pad(s.getUTCHours())
            +":"+pad(s.getUTCMinutes())
            +":"+pad(s.getUTCSeconds())
        );
    },100);
})();
```

While this works nicely, it suffers if there is any delay between loading the HTML and running the JavaScript. This is especially true if a tab is opened in the background, as it may not run the JavaScript until it gains focus which could be seconds, minutes or even hours later.

My attempt at fixing this was to change the `local` line:

```
local = window.performance ? window.performance.timing.requestStart : Date.now()
```

This uses `requestStart` to determine what the local time was when the server generated the HTML.

How accurate is this? Reliable? Is there a different property of `window.performance.timing` that I should use instead? Is there another way to get the time from the server with reasonable accuracy?

Comment: what is your overall goal for this code?

Comment: @cmorrissey The project is a game, so it is important for user experience to know when server-time is to be able to accurately represent "thing X happens in Y amount of time".

Comment: Unless you trust the local time to be fully synchronized with the server time (for example if both are synchronized to a reliable central time service) you can't have an accurate representation of server time regardless of what you do (for many reasons, but just to name one - network latency)

Comment: @Amit That's the point of the code in the first place - the server says "this is the time I have", the browser takes that and compares it with local time (`offset` variable above). It then tracks time locally, offset by that amount.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps you overcome network or load delays - regardless of other tabs or side effects. If you want a "reliable" (still suffer from the exact same problems) view of server time, fetch it when you need it (xhr, ws, sse...)

Comment: @Amit The main issue is the delay between loading the page and running the JS. I'm hoping to find a solution, such as with `performance.timing`, that reduces this error margin.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why don't you make an ajax call to get the server time, based on server response time and network delay you would ideally be dealing with less then 1s lag.  On the other hand if your application is so time sensitive I don't think your current approach is the best, you would be better off with a real time server thats streaming data to the end user.

Comment: @cmorrissey That may be overkill... Ultimately I just want to avoid the issue of "if the JS doesn't run for some time after the actual page load, it will affect the displayed time"

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I don't know how one ajax call would be overkill but what do i know.

Comment: @cmorrissey Oh, I meant overkill for the time server streaming idea, sorry. An AJAX request could work - there's already a fairly regular AJAX request for notifications, I could add the server time to that and use it to correct any drift.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - ehhh, just to clarify, that's *precisely* what I suggested in my previous comment... Just saying...